# Library not found for -lAliyunOSSiOS when build in Xcode 13

Tags: xcode, react-native

The React Native 0.66.3 app on macOS Big Sur started to throw below when build in Xcode 13 yesterday without change I am aware of. The package is in app's `package.json`. Tried to `yarn add` and `pod install` a few times and the error remains.

Here is the module in `package.json`:

```
"aliyun-oss-react-native": "^1.0.0-alpha.7",
```

The module is under project's `node-modules`. Here is the build error in Xcode:

```
ld: library not found for -lAliyunOSSiOS
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Here is the module files listed under `iOS` of `aliyun-oss-react-native` :

[image]

Comment: Open this project in Xcode, and check under `library search paths` , Is there any path related to this library or not. 

Like `${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/AliyunOSS ` or   `${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/RNAliyunOSS ` . If not then add this and try building again.

Comment: Adding "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/PODS/AliyunOSSiOS" to Library search paths in Xcode for the project in Building setting works.